Pressing button in the main window to execute an even in user control
First, I would like to mention that I am a beginner with C#/WPF and trying to do my best to learn it.
I have a main window with multiple navigation buttons on its left side to navigate between user controls, which are showing in the middle of the main window. When clicking the buttons, an async API request is executed to a server and the response if presented in the user control area.
I added a progress indicator in the main window with a small x button on the top right of it to cancel the async request when needed. I added the progress indicator in the main window in order to cover majority of it so as long as it is running, the buttons on the left side will not be accessible. I am covering the buttons and the rest of the main window by the progress indicator.
As the progress indicator is resides in the main window, I am initiating it using mainWindow.ucProgressControl.Start().
I am trying to configure the small x button in a such way, when it pressed, the API request should stop.
How to configure an event handler when the x is being pressed, the user control request is terminated?
Originally, the progress indicator was configured in each user control and I had an event that was sending a cancellation token to the async requests, but after relocating the progress indicator to the main window, I am a little lost
